# Dialog Progress Fundo Branco opaco

Tags: java, android, material-design

Estou tentando há alguns dias chegar á um dialog progress transparente com um fundo branco opaco igual as imagens abaixo porém só conseguir chegar a fundo preto opaco no padrão do android já vi alguns apps que conseguiram fazer assim alguém ja conseguiu ? se conseguiram poderiam me ajudar como ? desde de já agradeço a ajuda de todos.

```
public static Dialog showDialogLoading(Context context, String msg) {
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context, R.style.AppThemeLoading);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.progress_dialog);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.corBranco_dialog)));
    dialog.show();
    return dialog;
}

<style name="AppThemeLoading" parent="Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
</style>

<color name="corBranco_dialog">#80ffffff</color>
```

[image: print tirado do app Wish dialog loading transparente com fundo branco]
[image: print tirado do app do PagSeguro dialog loading transparente com fundo branco]

Comment: Pra fazer isso você vai ter que setar o Alpha da cor

Comment: Poste seu código para vermos como está fazendo

Comment: @RaoniBZ editei a pergunta adicionando o código pode dar uma ajuda agora, ainda estou aprendendo a usar o stackoverflow

Comment: Tente dessa forma: `dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.R.color.transparent));` Se der certo, aí você cria uma cor referência, e muda só `(android.R.color.suacor)`.